# Is it safe to kill this process FilesyncSvc

Tags: azure, synchronization, ads

is it safe to do a taskkill /s servername /pid xxxx on this exe
including AzureStorageSyncMonitor.exe

i cannot rdp into this server, but everything else appears normal
cannot psservice, psexec, can do some wmi queries, but cannot stop/start service remotely

cannot do a reboot at the moment, so i was thinking my only might be to kill the process

the filesyncsvc exe is takig up 7GB ram, and i have cloud tiering enabled

at the moment, the server appears offline in storage sync services anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be killed, but tiered files will not function until the service starts back up.

Aung Oo
Azure Storage, Microsoft